# Does spliting large IIAF to smaller functions improve performance?

Tags: javascript, performance

I was checking Google Search page and I noticed that they do something like below:

```
(function(){
    window.google={}; // few keys (none of the keys is function)
})();

// immediately after, same script tag
(function(){
    google.x = function(){ /* ... */ };
    google.y = function(){ /* ... */ };
})();
// anonymous function invocations repeat
```

Is it possible that splits like that can improve overal performance at all? Second question - would the performance gains be any different if one would put each function in separate `<script>` tag?

Comment: No, that should make no significant difference at all.

Comment: Why do you think it would be faster? It's more code to parse, process and evaluate. I don't see a benefit.

Comment: For *some* cases there might be a benefit when global functions don't close over many unnecessary variables, but your example doesn't show that.

Comment: @Bergi, I though this could be faster because you parse small function, execute it and in the same time rest of the code (ie. next function) can be parsed.

Comment: @ArturRychlewicz That's not how it works - the whole code is parsed (and checked for syntax errors), then executed. But even if the processes were intermingled, parsing all lines and executing all lines still takes the same amount of time. That the first line might be executed a tiny bit earlier would hardly be noticeable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No performance benefit, in fact, it should be slightly slower. In general, IIFEs are used to protect against globals being accidentally created. The IIFE in this example is partially useless since it is setting up globals.

I suspect this is the result of having a base.html template  (or something like that), and some application/page specific scripts being added in dynamically.

I imagine the base.html file might look something like this:

```
<body>
...
<script>
  {{> iife script="window.google={}" }}
  {{#each scripts}}
      {{> iife script=script }}
  {{/each}}
</script>
</body>
```

I'm using handlebars, but it could be any templating language. The `{{> iife }}` code represents rendering a "partial" template. Essentially, this would just wrap up any code in an IIFE. In the above example, we also loop through a variable called "scripts". Which is an array of strings.

In some specific app/page new inline scripts might be added like this:

```
scripts.push('google.x = function(){ /* ... */ };');
```

This allows for easy creation of new applications/pages that have all the same default settings/configuration. It also lets them add scripts to pages in a consistent way.